# Validation - (Form) Cancel button doesnt work

Tags: c#, validation

I am having problems with leaving my Form on `CancelButton_Clicked` event, because of my `Validating` events.

I have one textbox which has its own validating methods, and returns `e.Cancel = true` if input String is null or empty, else `e.Cancel = false`.

Now, i have this `CancelButton` which is just a regular button, and for which I would like to close the current form, somewhat like this:

```
CancelButton_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Close();
}
```

But if I do it like this, and if the textbox is left empty it doesnt pass validation, and I cant close the form. Validation icons just keep blinking.
I tried setting `CausesValidation` to `false`, I tried also this:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Stop the validation of any controls so the form can close.
    AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
    Close();
}
```

But none of this helped. Hope you could. Cheers

Comment: Do you set the CausesValidation to False through the designer or in code?

Comment: Set e.Cancel back to true in the FormClosing event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

am assuming, you have set `btnCancel.CausesValidation=false;` either through code or designer.

setting `CausesValidation=false` of `button`, will allow you to call the `Click` `event` of the `button`

now there are multiple things you can do.

1. simply unregister your `textbox` `validating` events inside `btn_Cancel` i.e.

   ```
   private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       textBox1.Validating -= new CancelEventHandler(textBox1_Validating);
       this.Close();
   }
   ```
2. simply use a boolean flag. set it to true inside your btnCancel event and use it inside validating event

   ```
   bool IsCancelBtnClicked=false;
   private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       IsCancelBtnClicked=true;
       this.Close();
   }
   private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Cancel=!IsCancelBtnClicked;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add a private boolean member, set it true in CancelButtonClicked and then use it in the validation(s)

Answer (score -1):

do you miss the line `this.Close()`