# Set CauseValidation to false but not working

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have validating event.

```
    private void EmployeeIDtextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        if (EmployeeIDtextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter EmployeeID.", "Invalid EmployeeID");
        }

    }
```

And set my cancelbutton causevalidation to false but when i hit the cancelbutton the messagebox still shows.

Comment: I check it the causevalidation is wrok correctly. where are you set cause validattion is true

Comment: yes I am validating a TextBox

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski  U need to set causes validation of the all the controls in the hierarchy of cancel button. Suppose the tree is Form-> Panel-> Button u need to set the causes validation to false for each of the form, panel n button

Comment: @akanksha how i will do it?

Comment: Where is your cancel button code?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata this.close();

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CausesValidation property of all the controls in the hierarchy of Cancel button to false.

For example: Form1 contains Panel1 and Panel1 contains your cancel button. You need to set the CausesValidation Property of Form1, Panel1 and Cancel button to false.

CausesValidation is a property of Control class. Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx)

The control allows to fire validating event if the CausesValidation is true which is its default value.

If the controls in hierarchy have CausesValidation true and they receive focus before u click on cancel button, Validating event will be fired.

To avoid disabling it everywhere for controls in panel1, you should use a separate panel or none for Cancel Button.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**:
I checked at my end. Whichever control gains focus while moving to the cancel button should have CausesValidation false.

Set the CausesValidation to false for the hierarchy of the TextBox except the TextBox itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool IsCancelBtnClicked = false;
    private void EmployeeIDtextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (EmployeeIDtextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter EmployeeID.", "Invalid EmployeeID");
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsCancelBtnClicked = true;
        EmployeeIDtextBox.Validating -= new CancelEventHandler(textBox4_Validating);
        this.Close();
    }
```

Thanks to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16113700/2322994. :)